# How to view the queried data in listview in realm database?

Tags: android, listview, realm

I am new to realm database,I am facing the issue in the realm database querying the data from the database. The queried data from the database it looks like the below image [image]

I need to view the queried data in one by one in the listview.

The code for  add the data into the realm database.

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Realm mRealm;
    EditText editText;
    Button btn,btnNext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
        mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String newNames = editText.getText().toString();
                mRealm.beginTransaction();
                MyNames names = mRealm.createObject(MyNames.class);
                names.setName(newNames);
                mRealm.commitTransaction();
                editText.setText("");
            }
        });
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }

}
```

The code for querying the data from the database.

```
 public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listview;
    private Realm mRealm;
    Button next;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        listdata();
        listAdapter();
    }

    public List<RealmResults<MyNames>> listdata()
    {
        List<RealmResults<MyNames>> names = new ArrayList<>();
        mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmQuery<MyNames> data = mRealm.where(MyNames.class);
        RealmResults<MyNames> newData = data.findAll();
        names.add(newData);
        return  names;
    }

    public void listAdapter()
    {
        List<RealmResults<MyNames>> newData = this.listdata();
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_simple,R.id.textname,newData);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

public class MyNames extends RealmObject {

```
        String name;
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

Please help how to view the queried data from the database in listview one by one .

Comment: `List<RealmResults<MyNames>> names = new ArrayList<>();` but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RealmBaseAdapter`

The code for querying the data from the database.

```
 public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.list)
    ListView listview;

    Realm realm;

    @OnClick(R.id.button2) 
    public void clickButton2() {
        // do next
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmResults<MyNames> results = realm.where(MyNames.class).findAllAsync();
        MyNamesAdapter myNamesAdapter = new MyNamesAdapter(results);
        listView.setAdapter(myNamesAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyNamesAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<MyNames> {
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
    }

    public MyListAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection<Counter> realmResults) {
        super(realmResults);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (adapterData != null) {
            MyNames item = adapterData.get(position);
            viewHolder.text.setText(item.getName());
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

So you should use `RealmResults<T>` with `RealmBaseAdapter` from https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters

Comment: I have one doubt , i can use Custom Adapter instead of using the RealmBaseAdapter

Comment: Only if you use `RealmChangeListener` that you add to `RealmResults` which calls `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @PrabhaKaran also next time please refer to the documentation examples that show how to use Realm with ListView https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#examples

Comment: Now the data viewed one by one in the listview but the data are like MyNames = [{names:hi}],MyNames = [{names:Kumar}]..in this how can i remove the brackets ans view only the values

Comment: you need to do `viewHolder.text.setText(item.getName());` instead of `item.toString()`, and you shouldn't use ArrayAdapter which uses `toString()`

Comment: Oh you're using the other answer. Stop using that answer and start using this answer. This is not the other answer, so of course the other answer won't work.

Comment: Ok @EpicPandaForce , please help me what is reason for using using your method than another method.

Comment: The other answer will crash if you delete a `MyNames` from the Realm and you scroll up/down, and also shows `[ MyNames: {stuff} ]`?

Comment: @PrabhaKaran my answer is more of a quick fix for your current scenario. If you are looking for a robust solution that makes more sense to use in a real app, you should use this solution here

Comment: Tkhs @EpicPandaForce for sharing your valuable time with me,i read the realm documentation example but when i work in project some doubts are arising so only i posted this question.

Comment: i am trying to use it in ExpandableListView, and i set it up for parent list but unable to setup for child. please help

Answer (score 1):

`newData` is a `List<RealmResults<MyNames>>`. The listview displays items from the `List<>`, which are `RealmResult<MyNames>`, which is a "collection" of its own, causing the list to only display 1 item holding all the objects.

However you want to display individual MyNames items in the listview, not RealmResults.

You are likely looking for something like this (simplified a bit)

```
public List<MyNames> listdata()
{
    mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    return mRealm.where(MyNames.class).findAll();
}

public void listAdapter()
{
    List<MyNames> names = listdata();
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_simple,R.id.textname,newData);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Also, don't forget to close the realm in `Activity#onDestroy()`

Comment: Now the data viewed one by one in the listview but the data are like MyNames = [{names:hi}],MyNames = [{names:Kumar}]..in this how can i remove the brackets ans view only the values

Comment: If you want to use ArrayAdapter you have to collect the String from each MyName object and pass that collection into the adapter constructor. Otherwise you are better off using the other solution. It is way better suited for custom data display

Comment: Tkhs for your answer @ Tim Castelijns

Comment: Sure. Although it does not explain why your current code does not work, the solution in other answer is better. You might want to accept that one instead